# How to make an image grow in size with pygame

Tags: python, pygame, transform, scale

In a game that I'm making, I have an image that I need to scale from (old_width, old_height) to (new_width, new_height), so that it seems it's growing bigger, and I need to do that multiple times during the game.

So far, I've tried with pygame.trasform.smoothscale, but for some reasons all it does is it's moving the image along the screen toward the right corner.

It seems very strange to me, because I don't understand what is going on.

Here is the class that handles the image:

```
class GrowingImage:

    def __init__(self, image_path, x, y, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        self.object_image = pygame.image.load(image_path)

        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.object_image, (self.width, self.height))

        self.x_pos = x
        self.y_pos = y

    def draw(self, background):
        background.blit(self.image, (self.x_pos, self.y_pos))

    def grow(self):
        self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.object_image, (self.width, self.height))
        self.width += 1
        self.height += 1
```

And this is where the method grow is called. I deleted all the rest that is superfluous for this question, so theoretically the image should grow endlessly at this point:

```
image = GrowingImage('image.png', 400, 100, 405, 640)

while not is_game_over:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Bunch of stuffs

     # Redraw the screen
     self.game_screen.fill(WHITE_COLOR)
     image.grow()
     image.draw()

     # Display the screen
     pygame.display.update()

     # Tick the clock to update everything within the game.
     clock.tick(self.TICK_RATE)
```

Well, it doesn't and I've absolutely no idea why this happens. Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The image isn't really moving. It might look like its moving towards the bottom-right corner because its getting bigger i.e. its width and height are increasing, which remember, starts at the top left corner of the image. That is where it is drawn as well. So to make it look like its growing, you can offset where its drawn my half the width and the height, which basically means offset it so that it is drawn at the centre. Replace

```
background.blit(self.image, (self.x_pos, self.y_pos))
```

with

```
background.blit(self.image, (self.x_pos - (self.width/2), self.y_pos - (self.height/2)))
```

Working Example

```
import pygame

class GrowingImage:

    def __init__(self, image_path, x, y, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

        self.object_image = image_path

        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.object_image, (self.width, self.height))

        self.x_pos = x
        self.y_pos = y

    def draw(self, background):
        background.blit(self.image, (self.x_pos - (self.width/2), self.y_pos - (self.height/2)))

    def grow(self):
        self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.object_image, (self.width, self.height))
        self.width += 1
        self.height += 1


pygame.init()

d = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))
image = pygame.Surface((1, 1))
growingImage = GrowingImage(image, 300, 300, 20, 20)

while True:
    d.fill((255, 255, 255))
    pygame.event.get()

    growingImage.draw(d)
    growingImage.grow()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I see that my question has been closed because it was similar to another one, but thank you anyway for taking the time of reading my question and answering it, it's really well explained.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd argument of [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) can be a rectangle. Use a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object,  to scale an image with respect to its center:

```py
class GrowingImage:

    def __init__(self, image_path, x, y, width, height):
        
        self.object_image = pygame.image.load(image_path)
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.object_image, (self.width, self.height))

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft = (x, y))

    def draw(self, background):
        background.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def grow(self):
    
        w = self.rect.width + 1
        h = self.rect.height + 1
        self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.object_image, (w, h))
        
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = self.rect.center)
```

See also [Transform scale and zoom surface](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_surface_scale_and_zoom.md#transform-scale-and-zoom-surface)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time of reading my question and answering it, and also for the link, I've added it to my bookmarks!

Comment: I have some difficulties putting the pieces together... if I increase the growth, let's say from 1 to 10, I lose the center properties, how can I keep them consistant?

Comment: @Kyle This would not happen if you followed my suggestions correctly.